# I have this error file Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module, In my .js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, extensions

Good Morning Every Body When I compile my js file , in my console have this error

[image]

> What I Doing Wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `defined` use `require` Like this:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    "jquery/ui"
], function($){
    'use strict';
    //Your Js code here
});
```

This will surely fix the error that you are facing

Comment: Very Thanks I Fixed the error

Comment: Great. You are welcome :)